# Odoo - Currency sign not displaying in the qWeb

Tags: odoo-9, qweb

I have got a custom report and the currency sign is not displayed.
What could be wrong in this:

```
<span t-esc="grand_total" t-options="{'widget': 'monetary', 'display_currency': res_company.currency_id}"/>
```

Comment: The first question is. Is res_company.currency_id set? What can you see when you "print" <span t-esc="res_company.currency_id"/> ?

Comment: When I use <span t-esc="res_company.currency_id.name"/> it show the currency name of my company rather than customer company(report is printing customer statement).
I have tried to use partner_id.currency but if the customer is from Switzerland  and we are invoiceing in EUR the CHF would be displayed. Should I provide the entire code?

Answer (score 0):

You should use currency from invoice object. Change t-esc to t-field. What can you see when you just add t-field="grand_total" ?

```
<span t-field="grand_total" t-options="{'widget': 'monetary', 'display_currency': o.currency_id}"/>
```

Comment: somehow still nothing